# How to get index from List<string> of specific item?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this List:

```
List<string> headers = new List<string>(); 
headers.Add("Red"); 
headers.Add("Blue"); 
headers.Add("Green");
headers.Add("Black");
```

And I have this function:

```
private int getColorIndex(string colorName , List<string> headers)
{
     int index = LINQ;
}
```

In `getColorIndex` function I want to write LINQ that returns the index of specific color from headers list(in colorName variable).

For example if colorName is **black** the value of index will be 3.

The `colorName` can contain big or small letters.

For example:

```
  colorName = Black or colorName = black
```

Any idea how can I write this LINQ?

Comment: `List<T>.IndexOf`? Why do you want to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Beware of duplicate entries though...

Comment: `List<T>.FindIndex()` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx

Comment: `FindIndex`... this is new *for me*! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need LINQ for that. `List` has an [`FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It takes a **predicate** and returns the index of the **first** element that matches. In the predicate you can compare the strings using `String.Equals` and use a `StringComparison` parameter to ignore the case.

```
private int getColorIndex(string colorName , List<string> headers)
{
     int index = headers.FindIndex(s => String.Equals(s, colorName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Not case insensitive

Comment: @AlexanderDerck missed that, updated the answer. Thank you